# dynamic update of running java program

Tags: java, updates

For a new software we are currently evaluating ways to update the software.

Basically the software is a tiny GUI-application written in Java which communicates with a server and often runs 24x7.

The requirements for updating the program are the following:

- Check for updates on startup
- Check for updates and update dynamically while running (upon user request, periodically or initiated from server)

Current findings:

- JWS is mainly for downloading and installing Applications during startup and has certain known limitations
- Install4j is far more than we need and therefore too complex for our application
- GetDown? Not sure if it is possible to check for updates dynamically while running

Are there other ways to achieve the requirements? Is it possible to achieve with getdown (I haven't found lots of documentation about this topic)?

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers.

Comment: If its tiny maybe rewrite it to Netbeans or Eclipse RCP, you will have auto update and many other features out of the box.

Comment: Is it an Eclipse RCP app? You could use p2.